# Need help Translating PHP to Python

Tags: php, python

I am using a REST library whose development team only supports PHP. Pretty much everything are finished except translating this part of their PHP code to my Python codebase. the "preg_match" is tough for me, please help.

Their PHP:

```
function strippadding($string) {
  $slast  = ord(substr($string, -1));
  $slastc = chr($slast);
  $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
  if (preg_match("/$slastc{" . $slast . "}/", $string)) {
    $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - $slast);
    return $string;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My Python:

```
def strip_padding_pay2go(string):
  last_string = string[-1]
  slast       = ord(last_string)
  slastc      = chr(slast)
  pcheck      = last_string[:-slast]

  if re.search("/" + str(slastc) + "{" + str(slast) + "}/", string):
      last_char =  len(string) - slast
      new_string = string[0: last_char]
      return new_string
  else:
      return False
```

But i keep failing ( returns False ).

Comment: You're looking for python's `re module`. Take a look at `re.findall` and `re.search`.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Python regexen don't use delimiters (starting and ending `/`)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

```
def strip_padding_pay2go(string):
  last_string = string[-1]
  slast       = ord(last_string)
  slastc      = chr(slast)
  pcheck      = last_string[:-slast]

  if re.search(str(slastc) + "{" + str(slast) + "}", string):
      last_char =  len(string) - slast
      new_string = string[0: last_char]
      return new_string
  else:
      return False
```